# Why doesn't the Route tab appear in Glimpse Web Debuggger?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, glimpse

I've just installed Glimpse Web Debugger for ASP.NET (Beta) - version 0.82. I installed it via the Package Manager console in Visual Studio 2010 and the installation was successful.  I'm trying to test it out using the ASP.NET Development server and the ASP.NET MVC 3 version of the MVCMusicStore demo site using the Razor view engine.

For some reason, however, the Routes tab does not appear when I turn Glimpse on and try to test the web app. The Glimpse settings in my web.config file (below) don't show any blacklisted plugins:

```
On = True
Allowed IP's = 
    127.0.0.1
    ::1
Allowed ContentType's =
    text/html
Blacklisted Plugins =
```

These are list of plugins that the Glimpse/Config page says are running:

```
Glimpse.Core.Plugin.Request
Glimpse.Core.Plugin.Environment
Glimpse.Core.Plugin.Trace
Glimpse.Core.Plugin.Config
Glimpse.Core.Plugin.Server
Glimpse.Core.Plugin.Session
```

The only tabs that appear are: Ajax / Config / Environment / Remote / Request / Server. The Trace tab appears, but is greyed out.  Glimpse seems like a useful tool and I'd like to be able to test/debug routes with it but I can't figure out why it's not working correctly.  I'd greatly appreciate any help with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It looks like you have only installed Glimpse, not [Glimpse.MVC3](http://www.nuget.org/List/Packages/Glimpse.Mvc3) which adds in the MVC functionality.

Go ahead and Install-Package Glimpse.MVC3 in the powershell console, or just use the GUI to install Glimpse.MVC3.

In the future Glimpse may ship additional plugin packs similar to MVC3. Image we could have Glimpse.SharePoint or Glimpse.Orchard...

Comment: Will the Glimpse MVC3 pack work with MVC2 if the server has MVC3 installed?

Comment: That is not a tested scenario at this point. I'm sure some of the tabs will work and others won't. Official MVC2 support may come in a future release.

Comment: any chance of route being added on the webforms package where folks are yet to migrate to mvc but do use routing?

Comment: It is in fact in the backlog to move the Routing tab from the MVC package to the core package. Look for this to happen before 1.0 is released